# Flask WTForm action to reroute form data from one flask endpoint to another, when the whole Flask API is accessed from behind KrakenD Gateway

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, krakend

So I have 2 routes in my Flask App

- `<host_name>/oauth/leg1`
- `<host_name>/oauth/leg2`

when the `/oauth/leg1` route validates it's inputs, it calls render_form() to render a form with the `form-action` rerouting to the `/oauth/leg2` route.

the form html looks like this

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('oauth.leg2') }}" method="POST">
  blah blah blah
</form>
```

the `url_for` call in the form action correctly renders the route path of `oauth/leg2`

All this works fine. Clicking submit on my form sends the form data to the `oauth/leg2` route and everything proceeds as desired.

Now, I also use the KarkenD API Gateway.
The gateway has a URL of `api.dev.tech/connect/v1`. So the host name is `api.dev.tech`, but additionally, I want my Flask API to be accessed only through the `connect/v1` path of my gateway.

so my KrakenD gateway settings are like so,

`api.dev.tech/connect/v1/oauth/leg1` gets forwarded to `<flask_app>/oauth/leg1`
`api.dev.tech/connect/v1/oauth/leg2` gets forwarded to `<flask_app>/oauth/leg2`

### My Problem

When I access `api.dev.tech/connect/v1/oauth/leg1`, it correctly validates my request and renders the form.
Upon clicking submit on my form, the `action` evaluates to `oauth/leg2`, and this path gets appending to the host (`api.dev.tech`)
So the form input data is being sent to `api.dev.tech/oauth/leg2` -> this is not a valid gateway path, and this fails.

The form input data SHOULD be sent to `api.dev.tech/`/oauth/leg2`

I dont know how to conditionally insert this `connect/v1` path into the form action URL (connect/v1 should only be inserted when the request is sent through KrakenD, not when the request is normally sent to the Flask host directly)

### What I've tried

added the `_external` option to `url_for` to render the full path - this instead starts rendering my Kubernetes service name (my flask app and krakend gateway are running on kubernetes)

### Possible solutions

- Always prepend `connect/v1` in my form action, and then my API is only accessible indirectly through the gateway, but unusable directly.
- Have a KrakenD setting that omits the connect/v1, so `api.dev.tech/oauth/leg2` gets forwarded to `<flask_app>/oauth/leg2`. I dont like this because now I have to have one outlier rule in my KrakenD config that is lacking the `connect/v1` path.
- Modify my Flask routes to also have the `connect/v1` prefix in them - now Flask API is accessible directly, and it is also usable indirectly through KrakenD.